# Why are these results different about 'frequency shifting'?

Tags: fft, dft

I think 'spec_ori' & 'spec_shifted' spectrum amplitude and phase are same in below code. Because of 'spectrum shiting property' ([What effect does a delay in the time domain have in the frequency domain?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/509/what-effect-does-a-delay-in-the-time-domain-have-in-the-frequency-domain)).
But both are different. why?

---

```
K = 4 * 10^10;
Fs = 10 * 10^6;
t_len = 40 * 10^(-6);
t=-t_len/2:1/Fs:t_len/2; % time axis in range
omega = -Fs/2:1/t_len:Fs/2;
chirp = exp(1i*pi*K*t.^2);
spec_ori = fft(chirp);
spec_shifted = fft((chirp .* exp(1i*2*pi*Fs*t)));
plot(angle(spec_ori)-angle(spec_shifted))
```

---

Comment: Well, the DFT (which `fft` implements) is bijective. Hence, if the input is different, the output *must* be different. So, I really don't see how the shift properties of the DFT let you assert these should be identical; on the contrary, the shift property even defines *how* these should be different.

Comment: (by the way, your `exp(1i*2*pi*Fs*t)` might not be what you think it is – plot its real and imaginary part)

Comment: @Marcus Müller thank you for your reply. I thought if spectrum shift to Fs(sampling frequency), it is same as the original spectrum because of spectrum folding(DFT property).

Comment: But you don't do that shift. You're doing a different shift. Hence my "by the way".

Comment: @Marcus Müller I don't know what you mean. If you don't mind, let me know your thinking.

Comment: wait. I just revisited this. And: **how** different are your angles? As said, **please** plot your `exp(1i*2*pi*Fs*t)` and notice what a point-wise multiplication does. (you're right, this is a shift by `Fs`, I was wrong about that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These angular errors are in the order of $10^{-10}$. These are numerical inaccuracies caused by the fact that `exp()` can't be arbitrarily exact.

"Exact" would mean that `exp(1i*2*pi*Fs*t)` would just yield a vector `[1 1 1 … 1]`; if you'd hit that, the input to the `fft` would be identical, because multiplication with $1$ doesn't *do* anything.

So, always consider the error relative to the phenomenon you're observing. You wondered about something that was about 200 dB lower in amplitude than the observed quantity.

Comment: Ok I see. Thank you for your answer & advise it was helpful.

Comment: Cool! You can thank me by accepting this answer.